# Display Authors Selectively

Tags: author

can I check if it's possible to hide some of the authors and display them selectively? For example, I would like to display Jerrell Seah (no avatar shown) into one of the main 12 who have avatars.

[image]

Thanks!

```
global $wpdb;

$authors = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, user_nicename from $wpdb->users WHERE user_nicename != '' ORDER BY display_name");
$i=1;
foreach($authors as $author) {
    echo "<div class='col-md-3 individual-author'>";
    if($i<=12){
        echo "<div class='author-image-container'>";
        echo "<a href=\"".get_bloginfo('url')."/author/";
        echo $author->user_nicename;
        echo "\">";
        echo get_avatar($author->ID,200);
        echo "</a>";
        echo '</div>';
    }
    echo "<div class='author-name'>";
    echo "<a href=\"".get_bloginfo('url')."/author/";
    echo $author->user_nicename;
    echo "\">";
    the_author_meta('display_name', $author->ID);
    echo "</a>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo ($i==12)?"<div class='clearfix horizontal-rule'><hr/></div>":"";
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Hello, I've added the codes already and nope it doesn't seem to be through a static array.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would avoid custom `SQL` if there are perfectly fine WordPress functions for your needs.

Otherwise there's a risk that you might leave vulnerabilities or *backdoors* to your database which might lead to complete loss/corruption of data in the future.

---

Like any other query: the more arguments you use, the *heavier* it gets. Just make sure it does what you want and avoid unnecessary arguments. Learn more here `->` [WP_User_Query()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query)

```
<?php

//Some selection of parameters (look codex for me)
$args = array(

    'role'           => 'Subscriber',
    'include'        => array( 1, 2, 3 ), //user IDs
    'exclude'        => array( 4, 5, 6 ), //user IDs
    'search'         => 'Rami', //Keyword search
    'user_login'     => 'demo-user',
    'user_nicename'  => 'Demo User',
    'user_email'     => 'demouser@mailythingy.com',
    'user_url'       => 'www.demouserwebsite.com',
    'number'         => 5, //Count of users to get
    'orderby'        => 'post_count' //How to order them
);

$authors = new WP_User_Query( $args );

?>
```

---

**If you want to change the order of single authors**, Im afraid you'll need to add new user meta *(int)* to all authors. This would serve as order number which you can use as `orderby` argument.

Comment: Heya, thanks for the tip!

But yea if I were to go about replacing it, how should i do it? I'm sorry am pretty much a php noob trying to figure things out.